# Spring Boot 2.1.2 + POSTMAN + 415 Unsupported Media "application/json"

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I know this question is answered multiple times but somehow I am not able to get past it. Also, I haven't found **Unsupported Media "application/json"** error.

**EDIT: @RequestBody works when I select x-www-form-urlencoded in POSTMAN but not with raw -> application/json**

I just want to create a record by posting data from POSTMAN.

Here is my code:

Spring Boot Version: 2.1.2

I read that jackson data bind is already there in 2.1.2 version of spring boot.

### POSTMAN Request:

```
Body -> raw -> application/json

{
  "first_name": "ashutosh",
  "middle_name": "",
  "last_name": "pandey",
  "gender": "male",
  "address": "my address"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "firstName": "ashutosh",
  "middleName": "",
  "lastName": "pandey",
  "gender": "male",
  "address": "my address"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "practitioner": {
  "first_name": "ashutosh",
  "middle_name": "",
  "last_name": "pandey",
  "gender": "male",
  "address": "my address"
  }
}
```

### POSTMAN Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

### **Spring Boot Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/practitioner")
public class PractitionerController{
@Autowired private CrudService<Practitioner> crudService;

/**
 * POST /create --> Create a new Practitioner and save it in the database.
 */
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Practitioner practitioner) 
{
    crudService.save(practitioner);
    String practitionerId = String.valueOf(practitioner.getId());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(practitionerId);
}
}
```

### **My Entity**

```
package auto.nicu.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

@Entity
@Table(name="practitioners")
public class Practitioner implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6017382414498150143L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id") private Integer id;

@Column(name="gender", length=256) private String gender;
@Column(name="address", length=256) private String address;
@Column(name="last_name", length=256) private String lastName;
@Column(name="first_name", length=256) private String firstName;
@Column(name="middle_name", length=256) private String middleName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="practitioner") Set<PractitionerAction> practitionerActions;

public Practitioner() {}

/************* Getters *******************/

public Integer getId() {  return id; }  

public String getGender() {  return gender; }
public String getAddress() {  return address; }
public String getLastName() {  return lastName; }
public String getFirstName() {  return firstName; }
public String getMiddleName() {  return middleName; }

public Set<PractitionerAction> getPractitionerActions() {  return practitionerActions; }

/************* Setters *******************/

public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

public void setGender(String gender) { this.gender = gender; }
public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }
public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) { this.middleName = middleName; }

public void setPractitionerActions(Set<PractitionerAction> practitionerActions) { this.practitionerActions = practitionerActions; }
}
```

Whatever I do, I always get:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-04-01T11:46:15.420+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:224)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter....
```

**I tried removing @RequestBody, added consumes="application/json" or consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, the error is gone but I get null values in database.**

**I tried to create a simple html form and submitted data with jquery, but same error :(**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/practitioner/',
            method: 'post',
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization':'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU0MTcxNzA0fQ.o7AYTb8sE0iT5YMLndPUnkvdK5-sWG3u26gfK9z56ls',
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Is it a misleading error?

Here is the error stack trace:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-04-02T02:29:27.522+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: 
Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:224)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)\n\tat     
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat 
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat 
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat 
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n","path":"/practitioner/"}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Change @PostMapping(headers="Accept=application/json") for @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Also in Postman use request to user CammelCase instead of _

For Example

user `firstName` instead of `first_name`, 
OR

you can set `JsonProperties` to Practitioner to receive the properties as you want.

Comment: Updated code, removed headers, added consumes, using camel case now, added stack trace, still error :(

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems here. I would try to:

1. Remove "Accept: application/json" from Postman. This header means the client only accepts "application/json" as response type
2. Remove (headers="Accept=application/json") in @PostMapping
3. Remove @ResponseBody as it is not needed in @RestController

What is the content of your Practitioner class? The path of your Postman request is **/practitioner** ?

Comment: Tried but same problem :( , added Practitioner class above

Comment: You should use the first body (without "practitioner") in Postman. Use camel case for names (firstName, middleName, lastName) as the default configuration of objectMapper uses getter / setter for serialization / deserialization

Can you post the exception stacktrace as well?

Comment: Hi @htn, added stack trace

Comment: Yes, the path is /practitioner

Comment: You should post the stack trace from the server side, it is easier to read.

If the error is gone, use debug in your controller method to understand why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some possible reasons here: http://javahonk.com/415-unsupported-media-type/